# How do I know which statistic is for which parameter when calculating joint sufficient statistics using factorization criteria?

Tags: mathematical-statistics, inference, sufficient-statistics

For the normal distribution for example, after factorization we get

$\mathcal{L} = (2 \pi \sigma^2)^{-\frac{n}{2}}\exp\left(-\frac{n\mu^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2\sigma^2}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^2 - 2\mu\sum_{i=1}^n x_i\right)\right)
$

The factorization criteria tells us that $\sum(X_i)$ and $\sum(X_i)^2$ are jointly sufficient statistics, but how do I know which one is for the mean and which one is for the variance?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mean is not a sufficient statistic for the normal distribution when variance is not known?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/534967/mean-is-not-a-sufficient-statistic-for-the-normal-distribution-when-variance-is)

Comment: Also check this: [Do sufficient statistics for parameters of interest depend on whether nuisance parameters are known?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/507792/do-sufficient-statistics-for-parameters-of-interest-depend-on-whether-nuisance-p) and links there in.

Comment: There is no reason to have such a division in the statistics. Depending on the setting, the Rao-Blackwell estimate of one parameter may depend on all components of the sufficient statistic.

Comment: Although the question is not well-defined -- sufficient statistics needn't correspond one-to-one with parameters -- much can be learned by computing their expectations.  In this case, the expectation of one of them depends *only* on $\mu$ while the expectation of the other depends on both $\mu$ and $\sigma.$